# How to read EventLogFile without using Salesforce ELF Browser?

Tags: eventlogfile

I need to read the [Salesforce EventLogFile logs](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_download). I tried to connect to the [Salesforce ELF Browser](https://github.com/abisek/salesforce-elf-browser) but it is not working for me, as it just shows this error every time I login:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

[image]

I've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/abisek/salesforce-elf-browser/issues/78), but I may not ever be able to access this tool and need an alternate way to read the EventLogFile logs.

Does anyone know how to read EventLogFile without using Salesforce ELF Browser?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to vote down my question, can you at least let me know how I might improve it?

Comment: Have you configured that ELF Browser on your own platform or just deployed it to Heroku? Also, are you wanting to examine the EventLogFile logs as a one off exercise or as part of a business process? The content of each of the log files is base64 encoded so it's possible to convert that back to .csv via tools like powershell, but that would be for more ad-hoc analysis of the contents.

Comment: So, I have seen this error a bunch recently and interestingly, sometimes the browser returns the results if you wait a bit or click reload or try again with a slightly different query. Frustrating to be sure. Otherwise the REST APIs as saroj says; also, if you're using a backup tool, you can locate the event log files in your backup archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using the [ELF Browser application](https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/), you can use the Salesforce [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) to view the Event Log Files.

For further reference, review the Using Event Monitoring (https://sfdc.co/UsingEM) guide in the REST API Developer Guide and for a comprehensive list of the event types and their use cases refer to the Supported Event Types (https://sfdc.co/SupportedEventTypes) in the Event Log File object.

Source - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390089&type=1